# How much can I chain bash commands?

Tags: zshrc

Very quick question.  I have put together a few aliases to make these tedious bluetooth gymnastics that Apple has forced down our throats over the past few years a lot easier.  My question is in the following bash aliases may I chain multiple "&&'s or &'s" together so that I don't have to make multiple aliases in my .zshrc file?  For instance this is what I currently have:

```
alias sonosconnect="bluetoothconnector --connect 54-2a-1b-bf-2c-dc && switchaudiosource -s SonosRoam"
alias sonos="blueutil -p 1 && sonosconnect"
alias bton="blueutil -p 1"
```

My end result would essentially be combining these 3 aliases into one long alias, is this possible by using more than one instance of an &&?

Comment: They aren't `bash` aliases if you are using `zsh`.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using aliases at all. Use functions instead.

```
sonosconnect () {
  bluetoothconnector --connect 54-2a-1b-bf-2c-dc && switchaudiosource -s SonosRoam
}

sonos () { 
  blueutil -p 1 && sonosconnect
}

bton () {
  blueutil -p 1
}

some_name_for_all () {
    sonosconnect
    sonos
    bton
}
```

There's no significant limit on how long the command line can be, but there are very few situations where an alias is a better choice than function, and *many* cases where a function is the better or even only appropriate choice.

Comment: I see thank you.  Two follow up questions for you:

Am I able to call a function at any time just the same way that I would call an alias?

Also I can just put a function anywhere in my .zshrc file as well?

Comment: @jbeachy a function is like a more flexible alias so it can be anywhere an alias can be